# POM entries for Hadoop (version 2.4) with HBase (version 0.94.18)

Tags: maven, hadoop, hbase, pom.xml

What are the POM entries for Hadoop (version 2.4) with HBase (version 0.94.18)

Do i have to use hadoop-core? If so, which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- Hadoop Client -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- HBase -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.94.18</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You don't need Hadoop core, all you need is `hadoop-client` and the version should the same version as your hadoop version.